# HP QuickTest Professional Menu Issues

Tags: asp.net, menu, devexpress, infragistics, qtp

My QA is using HP QuickTest Professional to test our asp.net websites, and they are having a problem with menus. When using the Object Spy, each navigation group is being off centered, when hovering over the navigation menu item it is showing the box above the item on every navigation item, and the last few select the entire DIV tag.

This happens in both DevExpress Navigation Control and Infragistics.

Anyone else have this issue? Or know a way to fix this?

Comment: No solution that I know of, I'm afraid. The DevExpress controls do not have any built-in support for QTP, nor do we have firm plans to add it. Cheers, Julian (CTO)

Answer (score 1):

QTP supplies WebExtensibility as a method of adding support for custom web controls. You could write a WebExtensibility project that adds support for the problematic controls.